# How to reduce image size when the text is large instead of cropping it in HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, image

I want the Image to be displayed without cropping or being hidden, by just reducing its size when the text is increased and the wrapped text takes more space

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell">
         <h5>
                <span>"CATxxx45asdfghj 654654654 654654 65465 46546 54654 654654 kl;lkjhgfdsaWERTYUIOPOIUYTREWxcvbnm,mnbvcx"</span>
          </h5>
        <img src="http://www.placekitten.com/235/75">
    </div>

    <div class="cell">
         <h5>
            <span>"CAT"</span>
         </h5>
            <img src="http://www.placekitten.com/235/75">
    </div>
</div>
```

as in the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/nakulkudra/3odug6nt/

the second cell is normal , but when we have large text as it is in the first cell, the image is out of the cell and is cropped as the

**OVERFLOW is HIDDEN**,

what i want is the image size should be reduced to fit the available space...

please guide ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the (new) [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=flex&topic=css) property:

It basically tells the `.kitten` div to occupy the rest of the space.
And with some background properties set to `contain`, you get your kitten inside it!

This is [supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) by all recent browsers.

```css
.cell {
    border: 2px solid black;
    vertical-align: top;
    height:170px;
    width:200px; word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:flex; /* This is relatively new, but widely supported */
    flex-direction: column; /* the children will form a column */
}
.kitten{
    background: url(http://www.placekitten.com/235/75) no-repeat center center; 
    background-size:contain; /* To reduce the background to fit inside the div */
    flex:1; /* This "weight" tells to occupy the remaining space */
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell">
        <h5>
            <span>"CATxxx45asdfghj 654654654 654654 65465 46546 54654 654654 kl;lkjhgfdsaWERTYUIOPOIUYTREWxcvbnm,mnbvcx"</span>
        </h5>
        <div class="kitten">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <h5>
             <span>"CAT"</span>
        </h5>
        <div class="kitten">
        </div>
    </div>     
</div>
```

Comment: And you can also adjust the position of the background (for instance always at the very bottom)

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove `.cell {height:170px;}` so that image can expand your block.

Other option would be to use JS/jQuery and calculate *free space*:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var freeSpace = $('.cell').outerHeight() - $('.cell h5').outerHeight(true);
  $('.cell img').css('max-height', freeSpace);
});
```

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  height: 1px;
}
.cell {
  border: 2px solid black;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 170px;
  width: 200px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table">
  <div class="cell">
    <h5>
    <span>"CATxxx45asdfghj 654654654 654654 65465 46546 54654 654654 kl;lkjhgfdsaWERTYUIOPOIUYTREWxcvbnm,mnbvcx"</span>
  </h5>
    <img src="http://www.placekitten.com/235/75">
  </div>


  <div class="cell">
    <h5>
    <span>"CAT"</span>
  </h5>
    <img src="http://www.placekitten.com/235/75">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: no i dont want to expand the box, i want image size to be reduced

Comment: @N.K Check jQuery solution than

Answer (score 0):

add this css to your code where `Position:absolute` let your image static so it will be never hide and `width:200px` same width of your div container so image will never transcends borders of your div.

```
img{
    position: absolute;
    width:200px;
}
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.